# "Missed a PM interrupt" in syslog

Tags: 11.10

I've recently started getting the following messages in /var/log/syslog about every minutes. Googled "Missed a PM interrupt" but no useful results have come up.

Except that sudo is somewhat slower than it was used to be, nothing seems wrong with my server for now. Can I ignore this messages?

```
Apr 25 07:45:12 whale kernel: [479065.384519] ------------[ cut here ]------------
Apr 25 07:45:12 whale kernel: [479065.384538] WARNING: at /build/buildd/linux-3.0.0/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/i915_irq.c:649 ironlake_irq_handler+0x971/0x980 [i915]()
Apr 25 07:45:12 whale kernel: [479065.384541] Hardware name: MS-7680
Apr 25 07:45:12 whale kernel: [479065.384543] Missed a PM interrupt
Apr 25 07:45:12 whale kernel: [479065.384545] Modules linked in: snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek i915 snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hwdep snd_pcm coretemp drm_kms_helper drm snd_timer snd soundcore usb_storage psmouse         snd_page_alloc i2c_algo_bit serio_raw lp uas shpchp mei(C) video parport ahci libahci r8169
Apr 25 07:45:12 whale kernel: [479065.384573] Pid: 0, comm: swapper Tainted: G        WC  3.0.0-17-generic-pae #30-Ubuntu
Apr 25 07:45:12 whale kernel: [479065.384576] Call Trace:
Apr 25 07:45:12 whale kernel: [479065.384585]  [<c1050722>] warn_slowpath_common+0x72/0xa0
Apr 25 07:45:12 whale kernel: [479065.384596]  [<f88e6be1>] ? ironlake_irq_handler+0x971/0x980 [i915]
Apr 25 07:45:12 whale kernel: [479065.384606]  [<f88e6be1>] ? ironlake_irq_handler+0x971/0x980 [i915]
Apr 25 07:45:12 whale kernel: [479065.384611]  [<c10507f3>] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x33/0x40
Apr 25 07:45:12 whale kernel: [479065.384621]  [<f88e6be1>] ironlake_irq_handler+0x971/0x980 [i915]
Apr 25 07:45:12 whale kernel: [479065.384627]  [<c10b42cb>] try_one_irq+0x7b/0xe0
Apr 25 07:45:12 whale kernel: [479065.384634]  [<c154b9ce>] misrouted_irq+0x4d/0x75
Apr 25 07:45:12 whale kernel: [479065.384638]  [<c10b45e2>] note_interrupt+0x82/0x150
Apr 25 07:45:12 whale kernel: [479065.384642]  [<c10b2b4e>] handle_irq_event_percpu+0x9e/0x200
Apr 25 07:45:12 whale kernel: [479065.384647]  [<c102df58>] ? default_spin_lock_flags+0x8/0x10
Apr 25 07:45:12 whale kernel: [479065.384652]  [<c155dbad>] ? _raw_spin_lock_irqsave+0x2d/0x40
Apr 25 07:45:12 whale kernel: [479065.384657]  [<c10b2ceb>] handle_irq_event+0x3b/0x60
Apr 25 07:45:12 whale kernel: [479065.384661]  [<c10b4da0>] ? unmask_irq+0x30/0x30
Apr 25 07:45:12 whale kernel: [479065.384666]  [<c10b4dee>] handle_fasteoi_irq+0x4e/0xc0
Apr 25 07:45:12 whale kernel: [479065.384668]  <IRQ>  [<c1565352>] ? do_IRQ+0x42/0xc0
Apr 25 07:45:12 whale kernel: [479065.384676]  [<c15651b0>] ? common_interrupt+0x30/0x38
Apr 25 07:45:12 whale kernel: [479065.384682]  [<c14500e0>] ? pci_mmcfg_write+0xe0/0x100
Apr 25 07:45:12 whale kernel: [479065.384687]  [<c145b582>] ? kfree_skb+0x12/0x90
Apr 25 07:45:12 whale kernel: [479065.384691]  [<c145ab07>] ? __skb_clone+0x27/0xd0
Apr 25 07:45:12 whale kernel: [479065.384697]  [<c151d839>] ? packet_rcv_spkt+0x69/0x140
Apr 25 07:45:12 whale kernel: [479065.384702]  [<c14672ae>] ? __netif_receive_skb+0x3de/0x4a0
Apr 25 07:45:12 whale kernel: [479065.384707]  [<c1467d9f>] ? netif_receive_skb+0x6f/0x80
Apr 25 07:45:12 whale kernel: [479065.384711]  [<c1467ec7>] ? napi_skb_finish+0x37/0x50
Apr 25 07:45:12 whale kernel: [479065.384715]  [<c1468331>] ? napi_gro_receive+0xa1/0xb0
Apr 25 07:45:12 whale kernel: [479065.384721]  [<f8432bec>] ? rtl8169_rx_interrupt.isra.67+0x9c/0x2b0 [r8169]
Apr 25 07:45:12 whale kernel: [479065.384728]  [<f8433c80>] ? rtl8169_poll+0x30/0x80 [r8169]
Apr 25 07:45:12 whale kernel: [479065.384733]  [<c14684fd>] ? net_rx_action+0x10d/0x220
Apr 25 07:45:12 whale kernel: [479065.384737]  [<c116f7b0>] ? aio_queue_work+0x30/0x30
Apr 25 07:45:12 whale kernel: [479065.384742]  [<c1057350>] ? local_bh_enable_ip+0x90/0x90
Apr 25 07:45:12 whale kernel: [479065.384746]  [<c10573d1>] ? __do_softirq+0x81/0x1a0
Apr 25 07:45:12 whale kernel: [479065.384751]  [<c1057350>] ? local_bh_enable_ip+0x90/0x90
Apr 25 07:45:12 whale kernel: [479065.384753]  <IRQ>  [<c1057716>] ? irq_exit+0x76/0xa0
Apr 25 07:45:12 whale kernel: [479065.384760]  [<c156535b>] ? do_IRQ+0x4b/0xc0
Apr 25 07:45:12 whale kernel: [479065.384764]  [<c1073a63>] ? __hrtimer_start_range_ns+0x163/0x400
Apr 25 07:45:12 whale kernel: [479065.384769]  [<c15651b0>] ? common_interrupt+0x30/0x38
Apr 25 07:45:12 whale kernel: [479065.384774]  [<c105007b>] ? unregister_exec_domain+0x4b/0x80
Apr 25 07:45:12 whale kernel: [479065.384779]  [<c12e32f7>] ? intel_idle+0xb7/0x110
Apr 25 07:45:12 whale kernel: [479065.384784]  [<c143fe0d>] ? cpuidle_idle_call+0x7d/0x240
Apr 25 07:45:12 whale kernel: [479065.384789]  [<c1008c7a>] ? cpu_idle+0x8a/0xc0
Apr 25 07:45:12 whale kernel: [479065.384793]  [<c152dd85>] ? rest_init+0x5d/0x68
Apr 25 07:45:12 whale kernel: [479065.384798]  [<c1802774>] ? start_kernel+0x352/0x358
Apr 25 07:45:12 whale kernel: [479065.384801]  [<c18023b3>] ? pass_bootoption.constprop.2+0xe2/0xe2
Apr 25 07:45:12 whale kernel: [479065.384805]  [<c18020ba>] ? i386_start_kernel+0xa9/0xaf
Apr 25 07:45:12 whale kernel: [479065.384808] ---[ end trace 49847d47cca5a812 ]---
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless your server is missing page hits and network connections time to time, or even keystrokes, missing an PM interrupt won't be a critical issue--barely noticeable. This appears to be linked to your video driver(Second line of your log) and unless there is screen corruption, or you are using your GPU for critical computation, you should not be worried.